# FPDF How to add break or new line in a cell in content

Tags: php

I am working on creation of pdf with dynamic content for this i am using fpdf.I need to add 
 in content if content is large.This is my code from where i am sending my conent.

```
 function myTest($obj,$text,$time)
 {
    $html = '';

     $html .='<B>Size: </B>'.$text.'<BR><B>Time: </B>'.$time;

     return $obj->WriteHTML5($html);    

 }
```

Comment: assuming that `$obj` is an fdpf instance, `WriteHTML5` is not a method of vanilla fpdf object. Have you loaded any addon? Which ones?

Comment: use \n within content where you want to add line break.